# WooCommerce How to use category link page

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, woocommerce

My link to site with product looks like:
`/produkt/komputery/acer/80/acer-mate/`

And i want to create site which service category link (for_example):

- `/produkty/komputery/`
- `/produkty/komputery/acer`

  1. `produkty` is a 'products' (Polish name of multiple product)
  2. `komputery` is a category
  3. `acer` is a subcategory of `komputery`

This link: `http://hostname/produkty/` works. It shows all site product. (fine) But links as above show main page.

**Question:**

1. How to show `http://hostname/produkty/komputery/acer` as `http://hostname/produkty/`? (of course these sites are the same, I mean that the first one is more filtred than second)

Comment: It is still clear what you want to do. Can you explain in more detail?